# glmnet: Convert predicted probabilities to predicted classes

Tags: r, glmnet

I ran `cv.glmnet` using a **Poisson distribution** for a binary outcome. The `predict` function returns predicted probabilities, but not predicted classes. How do I convert the probabilities into classes so I might generate a `confusionMatrix` to determine AUC, etc.? **NB.** At least one predicted probability is > 1.

```
cv <- cv.glmnet(deriv.x, deriv.y, foldid = foldid, weights = wts, family = "poisson")
pred <- predict.cv.glmnet(cv, newx = valid.x, s = "lambda.min", "response")
confusionMatrix(pred, valid.y)
Error in confusionMatrix.default(pred, valid.y) : 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference
```

Comment: check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38004/poisson-regression-for-binary-data) to see why it is a bad idea to use poisson regression for binary data

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're returning probabilities, not classes, so try it:

```
cv <- cv.glmnet(deriv.x, deriv.y, foldid = foldid, weights = wts, family = "poisson")
pred <- predict.cv.glmnet(cv, newx = valid.x, s = "lambda.min", "response")

pred <- ifelse(pred > 0.5,1,0) 

confusionMatrix(pred, valid.y)
```

You can choose your own value for rounding off.